# SocketTimeoutException while downloading data from Google Storage

Tags: java, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm getting a large number of SocketTimeoutException while downloading data from Google Storage. What's the best way to increase the timeout ?

**Use case**

Download 24 files (10GB total) in parallel from multiple servers using Map/Reduce.

**Source Code**

```
  Storage storage = new Storage.Builder(
                new NetHttpTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(),
                new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken))
            .setApplicationName("FooBar")
            .build();

  Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get(bucket, fn);
  getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
  getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3052)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3046)
    at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:51)
    at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:94)
    at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:63)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpDownloader.java:261)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:209)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:553)
    at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(Storage.java:4494)
```

**Edit**

This only happens when I download the data from Japan. Everything is fine from US-East and US-West.

Comment: Is this still happening for you today? There was a transient issue a little while ago affecting the uploads of some large files. Could you try it again and let me know if it's still failing for you?

Comment: It's happening right now from AWS in Tokyo. I'll try again from California tomorrow...

Comment: Interestingly there is no timeout from AWS in US-east.

Comment: I wonder if you found any solution? I use AWS and region us-west-2 (Oregon) and from time to time I do get this "timeout". I get it upon my first request to get directory listing of my "google drive" (**NOT** even upon transfer of large file).

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn't find any better solution than downloading the data from the US region instead of Japan, which was totally fine for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a variable called "CommandTimeout", or something of that nature. Usually that determines how long a connection can last before it flags an error.

"ConnectionTimeout" usually means how long the program can try to connect to your source, which isn't really what you need changed, as the connection happens fast, it's the download that is slow.

Comment: The location of this variable is precisely what I'm looking for. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: I just quickly wanted to check if you closed your connection. I'm not familiar with this API, but most downloaders need the connection closed at the end of their use.

Comment: The connection is managed internally by the API. I don't open it, neither close it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ...

1. Set the proxy in the linux box.
2. While creating storage - new NetHttpTransport() provide your own way to create the socket and add the proxy in the transport.

   ```
   public HttpClient myHttpClient() throws Exception {
       SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
       //SetRegisrty for both HTTP and HTTPS - Check google for this.
       schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
               .getSocketFactory(), YOUR_PROXY_PORT));
       schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory
               .getSocketFactory(), 443));

       HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
       HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 30 * 1000);  // SET the timeout
       HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
       ClientConnectionManager connManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
               params, schemeRegistry);
       DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager,
                   params);
       try {
           int proxyPort = YOUR_PROXY_PORT;
           String proxyHost = "YOUR_PROXT_HOST_NAME";
           if (proxyPort > 0 && proxyHost != null && proxyHost.length() > 0) {
               System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
               System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxyPort + "");
               System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
               System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort + "");
               HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
               httpClient.getParams().setParameter(
                       ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
           }
       } catch (NullPointerException e) {
           System.out.println("Proxy error here");
       }
       return httpClient;
   }

   public static HttpTransport myNetHttpTransport()
           throws Exception {
       return new ApacheHttpTransport(myHttpClient());
   }
   ```

Use `.setTransport(myNetHttpTransport())` instead of `NetHttpTransport()`.

We spent long time on this. but as of now this seems to be working. Please let me know if any help in this...

Comment: Hi JordanD, thanks, Iam new to stack and trying my best to get to know the process. Just posted the answer

Comment: This answer works for us. If this works for you let me know. If any doubts on the same, you can ping here