# Downloads from google storage fail randomly with SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm having the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009248/sockettimeoutexception-while-downloading-data-from-google-storage?newreg=037cbbdd15a8460c852523e280f37491) but unlike the author the issue is not gone away even if I connect from European or US-based servers.

I'm using pretty straightforward code to query the storage:

```
 Storage storage = new Storage.Builder(
                new NetHttpTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(),
                new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken))
            .setApplicationName("FooBar")
            .build();

 Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get(bucket, fn);
  getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
  getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

wrapped with map-reduce job.

When job is ran it fetches files (~15GB) in parallel using few nodes.
Some runs succeeds but some from time to time up to 50% of download attempts fail with the exception as below:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:755)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:116)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2676)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2671)
        at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:51)
        at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:94)
        at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:63)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpDownloader.java:261)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:209)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:553)
        at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(Storage.java:4494)
        at ***
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:771)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

I've tried using Amazon (region US_EAST_1) and own servers in Europe, but nothing helped. The download fails randomly.

Is there any way to configure the timeout in google storage client?
The OAuth2 access token is shared across all nodes of the cluster. Is there a quota for simultaneous connections to the google storage?

Comment: I wonder if you found any solution? I use AWS and region us-west-2 (Oregon) and from time to time I do get this "timeout". I get it upon my first request to get directory listing of my "google drive" (**NOT** even upon transfer of large file).